# How to use Python to connect to OceanBase's Oracle schema?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to use Python to directly connect to the Oracle database of OceanBase, but there is no Python example in the examples provided in the document. Only Java and C are available. Apart from indirectly calling Java or C packages to connect, are there any other open source packages or examples to connect.

Comment: You seem to be looking for this article: https://en.oceanbase.com/docs/common-oceanbase-database-10000000000829751

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the article only provides an example of connecting OceanBase's MySQL mode

Comment: Maybe you should search for how to connect to an Oracle database with Python. If I understand correctly, the Oracle mode of OceanBase is supposed to emulate an Oracle database (https://en.oceanbase.com/docs/enterprise-oceanbase-database-en-10000000000905632).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's sure that there is no such a python sdk to connect to oceanbase in oracle mode.

But you can ask your supporter to help and the requirement will be meet soon if there are a lot of users.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).